# Teaser Carousel View using UIScrollView programatically

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, autolayout, carousel

I want to implement a teaser carousel view(that is partial left and right view shown in the viewport along with the main view centered) using UIScrollView.

**View Hierarchy:**

ViewController -> ScrollView ->  Horizontal Stack View -> and 3 views embedded inside it

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        let scroll = CarouselView(views: [])
        view.addSubview(scroll)
        scroll.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            scroll.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
            scroll.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
            scroll.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor),
        ])
    }
}


class CarouselView: UIView, UIScrollViewDelegate {
    var views: [UIView] = []
    
    init(views: [UIView]) {
        super.init(frame: .zero)
        
        self.views = views
        
        scrollView.delegate = self
        
        setupSubviews()
        setupLayoutConstraints()
        setupDummyViews()
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    func setupSubviews() {
        addSubview(scrollView)
        scrollView.addSubview(stackView)
    }
    
    private func setupLayoutConstraints() {
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor),
            scrollView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor),
            scrollView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor),
            scrollView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 150.0),
            
            stackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.topAnchor),
            stackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.leadingAnchor),
            stackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.trailingAnchor),
            stackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.bottomAnchor),
            stackView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.heightAnchor)
        ])
    }
    
    private func setupDummyViews() {
        let view1 = UIView()
        view1.backgroundColor = .red
        
        let view2 = UIView()
        view2.backgroundColor = .yellow
        
        let view3 = UIView()
        view3.backgroundColor = .green
        
        let views = [view1, view2, view3]
        
        for view in views {
            stackView.addArrangedSubview(view)
            NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
                view.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.widthAnchor),
            ])
        }
    }
    
    // MARK: - UI Components
    let scrollView: UIScrollView = {
        let scrollView = UIScrollView()
        scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        scrollView.isPagingEnabled = true
        scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
        return scrollView
    }()
    
    let stackView: UIStackView = {
        let stackView = UIStackView()
        stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        stackView.axis = .horizontal
        stackView.spacing = 0.0
        stackView.distribution = .fillEqually
        stackView.alignment = .fill
        
        return stackView
    }()
}
```

**Problems:**

1. The views are not scrollable.
2. Left and right partial views not showing up. Please Guide me!!! Including cases while handling just 1, 2 and 3 views

Comment: Why do you choose UIScrollView, but not UICollectionView with custom layout? There will always be only 3 screens, no more?

Comment: something like this may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41207199/animated-custom-layout-in-uicollectionview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your current code, the reason you cannot scroll is because your `scroll` instance of `CarouselView` has no height.

By default, a `UIView` has `.clipsToBounds = false` -- so you can see any subviews that extend outside the frame of the view.

If you set `scroll.clipsToBounds = true` and run your code as-is:

```
    let scroll = CarouselView(views: [])
    scroll.clipsToBounds = true
```

You won't see **anything**.

Views that extend outside the frame of their superview cannot receive touches. So, even though you can *see* them, you cannot *interact* with them.

You missed an important line in your constraint setup:

```
scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor),
scrollView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor),
scrollView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor),
scrollView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 150.0),

// you need this line to give a height to "self"
scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor),
```

Now, you can scroll (and still see the views with `scroll.clipsToBounds = true`).

Next step is to get your carousel subviews to be less than the full `scroll` view width. However, setting `scrollView.isPagingEnabled = true` pages the *full width* of the scroll view.

Many different ways to approach this, including disabling `.isPagingEnabled` and handle the view positioning, deceleration, etc on our own; using a `UICollectionView` with calculated content insets; etc.

Or, we can get a little tricky...

Let's set the Width of the scrollView to the desired "partial" width, like this - light gray is the Carousel view background, and we have a black outline around the scroll view):

[image]

Now, as we scroll, we see this:

[image]

and with paging enabled it will "snap" to the next subview:

[image]

Sounds like we are part of the way... but, we also want to see the partial previous/next subviews.

So, let's set `scrollView.clipsToBounds = false`:

[image]

[image]

[image]

When trying that, though, we quickly find a problem.

Because the subviews are "visible but outside the frame" of the scroll view, we can only scroll by dragging within the scroll view itself (inside the black outline).

To allow dragging from any part of the view, we can implement `hitTest(...)` (inside the Carouself view class) like this:

```
override func hitTest(_ point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {
    if self.bounds.contains(point) {
        return scrollView
    }
    return super.hitTest(point, with: event)
}
```

Now, if the touch is inside the view, we tell the scrollView to use that touch. If it's outside the view, we return `super...` to allow the touch to act on any other UI elements.

Here's a complete example...

- I'm setting up the "dummy" views in the controller, to make it easier to test 1, 2, 3, etc views.
- I've made some changes to your constraints to use the scroll view's `.contentLayoutGuide` and `.frameLayoutGuide`
- I've also re-named your `scroll` view to `myCarouselView` to avoid confusion.

---

**view controller class**

```
class CarouselViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        let colors: [UIColor] = [
            .red, .green, .blue,
            .cyan, .magenta, .yellow,
        ]
        
        let numViews: Int = 3
        
        var views: [UIView] = []
        
        for i in 0..<numViews {
            let v = UIView()
            v.backgroundColor = colors[i % colors.count]
            views.append(v)
        }

        let myCarouselView = CarouselView(views: views)

        view.addSubview(myCarouselView)
        myCarouselView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            myCarouselView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
            myCarouselView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
            myCarouselView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor),
        ])
    
        // so we can see the view framing
        myCarouselView.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.9, alpha: 1.0)
        
    }
    
}
```

---

**CarouselView class**

```
class CarouselView: UIView, UIScrollViewDelegate {
    var views: [UIView] = []
    
    override func hitTest(_ point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {
        if self.bounds.contains(point) {
            return scrollView
        }
        return super.hitTest(point, with: event)
    }
    
    init(views: [UIView]) {
        super.init(frame: .zero)
        
        self.views = views
        
        scrollView.delegate = self
        
        setupSubviews()
        setupLayoutConstraints()
        
        for view in views {
            stackView.addArrangedSubview(view)
            NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
                view.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.frameLayoutGuide.widthAnchor),
            ])
        }
        
        // so we can see the views that are outside the frame of the scroll view
        scrollView.clipsToBounds = false
        
        // let's give the scroll view a border to make it clear
        scrollView.layer.borderWidth = 2
        scrollView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    func setupSubviews() {
        addSubview(scrollView)
        scrollView.addSubview(stackView)
    }
    
    private func setupLayoutConstraints() {
        
        let cg = scrollView.contentLayoutGuide
        let fg = scrollView.frameLayoutGuide
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor),
            scrollView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 150.0),
            scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor),

            scrollView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.60),
            scrollView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerXAnchor),
            
            stackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cg.topAnchor),
            stackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cg.leadingAnchor),
            stackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cg.trailingAnchor),
            stackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cg.bottomAnchor),
            
            stackView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: fg.heightAnchor),
            
        ])
    }
    
    // MARK: - UI Components
    let scrollView: UIScrollView = {
        let scrollView = UIScrollView()
        scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        scrollView.isPagingEnabled = true
        scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
        return scrollView
    }()
    
    let stackView: UIStackView = {
        let stackView = UIStackView()
        stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        stackView.axis = .horizontal
        stackView.spacing = 0.0
        stackView.distribution = .fillEqually
        stackView.alignment = .fill
        
        return stackView
    }()
}
```

---

**Edit**

If you want spacing between the carousel views, don't change the stack view spacing.

Instead, design your subviews to include the spacing.

For example, we can add a white `UIView` to act as the "visible frame", and add a centered label as a subiew. We will constrain the white view with 8-points on top and bottom, and 4-points on leading and trailing.

So, a single view will look like this:

[image]

and two of them side-by-side in the Zero-spacing stack view look like this:

[image]

We now have the visual effect of 8-points spacing between the subviews.

We can also "style" the subviews a little bit, like this:

[image]

[image]

[image]

So, **no changes** to the `CarouselView` class posted above.

We'll create the beginnings of a `CarouselCardView` class:

```
class CarouselCardView: UIView {
    
    let label: UILabel = {
        let v = UILabel()
        v.textAlignment = .center
        v.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 48.0, weight: .regular)
        return v
    }()
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    func commonInit() {
        
        // add a view with rounded corners be the "visible frame"
        let rv = UIView()
        rv.backgroundColor = .white
        
        rv.layer.cornerRadius = 12
        
        // let's give it a very light shadow
        rv.layer.shadowOffset = .init(width: 0.0, height: 1.0)
        rv.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        rv.layer.shadowRadius = 2.0
        rv.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
        
        rv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        addSubview(rv)
        addSubview(label)
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            rv.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor, constant: 8.0),
            rv.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: 4.0),
            rv.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor, constant: -4.0),
            rv.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor, constant: -8.0),

            label.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerXAnchor),
            label.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerYAnchor),
            
        ])
        
    }

}
```

and then in the example view controller, instead of "dummy" views with different color backgrounds, we'll create instances of `CarouselCardView`:

```
class CarouselViewController: UIViewController {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        
        let numViews: Int = 5
        
        var views: [UIView] = []
        
        for i in 0..<numViews {
            let v = CarouselCardView()
            v.label.text = "\(i)"
            views.append(v)
        }
        
        let myCarouselView = CarouselView(views: views)
        
        view.addSubview(myCarouselView)
        myCarouselView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            myCarouselView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
            myCarouselView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
            myCarouselView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor),
        ])
        
        // so we can see the view framing
        myCarouselView.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.9, alpha: 1.0)
        
    }
    
}
```

Comment: What updates need to be done if I want to have an 8px spacing between left and right partial views? Also when the first view is displayed in the viewport, no partial left view should be shown than the main view and 8px spacing and 8px partial right view. Adding spacing to the stack view causes irregular partial left and right view sizing @DonMag

Comment: @AniketPrakash - don't add spacing to the stack view. Instead, design your subviews to add the spacing. See the **Edit** to my answer.